# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when run javacpp

Tags: java, javacpp

I am using javacpp to access cpp from Java.

I have tried the example provided in the documentation

cpp code:

```
    CompletableFuture<Integer> futureInC(){
    @StdFuture f = @cppDemo.futureInC();
    CompletableFuture<Integer> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    f.then(int value -> future.complete(value));
    return future;
}
```

Java code:

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.annotation.*;

@Platform(include="LegacyLibrary.h")
@Namespace("LegacyLibrary")
public class LegacyLibrary {
    public static class LegacyClass extends Pointer {
        static { Loader.load(); }
        public LegacyClass() { allocate(); }
        private native void allocate();

        // to call the getter and setter functions 
        public native @StdString String get_property(); public native void set_property(String property);

        // to access the member variable directly
        public native @StdString String property();     public native void property(String property);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Pointer objects allocated in Java get deallocated once they become unreachable,
        // but C++ destructors can still be called in a timely fashion with Pointer.deallocate()
        LegacyClass l = new LegacyClass();
        l.set_property("Hello World!");
        System.out.println(l.property());
    }
}
```

I am getting following error if I run NativeLibrary.java file in Intellij Idea:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniNativeLibrary in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:597)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:438)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:381)
at com.viettel.demo.NativeLibrary$NativeClass.<clinit>(NativeLibrary.java:13)
at com.viettel.demo.NativeLibrary.main(NativeLibrary.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

How can I run example javacpp in Intellij Idea, I did try with command line following guilde in Readme.md without problem.
Thank for your support!

Comment: Which documentation are you talking about?  Link please

Comment: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp
I am using javacpp for JNI C++ to Java

Answer (score 1):

This set of exception is triggered when your application attempts to load a **native library** .In this case JVM is looking in both the **PATH environment** variable and the java.library.path system property.To fix this exception you need to set path for that library u are trying to load. Just like you set path for java.

Comment: I **think** that **we** would find your answer more **readable** if you didn't use so much **markup**.  And some proper sentences, capitalization, punctuation and so on would help.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same problem when I first use `javacpp` although I was using Eclipse rather than IntelliJ.

My guess is that your maven configuration file is incorrect and hence gcc compiler cannot find your source file `LegacyLibrary.h`.

Configure your pom.xml using the following link as a reference.

https://github.com/oltzen/JavaCppExample/blob/master/pom.xml

Pay attention to line 53 and 65. Fill in the correct package names. This helps the compiler find out where your `LegacyLibrary.h` is.

Also, watch this video clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZrrqZLhtmw which walks you through the whole process how to run Javacpp with maven and eclipse.